# Tkinter listbox, skip duplicate values from dictionary

Tags: python, tkinter

I have created a dictionary to store a filename as the key and file path as the value. The keys are then displayed in a list box which the user can select a file from and load:

```
filedict={}

def open_file():
    file_path = fd.askopenfilename(initialdir="/", title = "Select a File", filetypes = ((".CSV Files", "*.csv"), (".JSON Files", "*.json"), (".XML Files", "*.xml")))
    file_name = os.path.basename(file_path) 
    
    if file_path == "":
        messagebox.showerror("Information", "No file was selected.") 
    else:
        if file_name in filedict:
            messagebox.showerror("Information", "The file name already exisits \nPlease rename the file and try again.")
        else:
            filedict.update({file_name:file_path})
            add_file_to_list()

def add_file_to_list(): 
    for key, value in filedict.items():
        file_box.insert(END,key)

file_box = Listbox(root, height=10, selectmode="extended") # create listbox for files
file_box.pack()
```

The issue is with my add_file_to_list function, every time a new file is opened the previous items in the dictionary are duplicated in the list box due to how the for loop is constructed.

how can I alter my for loop so that it skips keys that already exist in the list box?

I have tried:

```
def add_file_to_list(): #TODO if item in list exists skip 
    for key, value in filedict.items():
        if key in file_box:
            print("duplicate")
        else:
            file_box.insert(END,key)
```

but I get a TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've figured it out. The Tkinter listbox does not have a contains() method so I wrote my own:

```
def add_file_to_list(): 
    for key, value in filedict.items():
        if contain(key) == True:
            pass
        else:
            file_box.insert(END,key)
        
def contain(key):
    item = key in file_box.get(0, "end")
    return item
```